# Subsequence and diagonal process

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations

We consider a sequence of functions défined on $\mathbb R^n$ by $f_m(x)=f(\frac{x}{m}),\   \forall m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that  :

1) $f=1 $ in $B(0,1)$

2) $\mathrm{supp\,} f\subset B(0,2)$

3) $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$

We  consider also a  sequence $(u_n)$ such that :

1) $u_n$ converges weakly to $0$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$

2) $||u_n||_{L^2(R^n)}=1$

I want to prove by a diagonal process that we can  extract a  subsequence of $f_mu_n$ which converges strongly in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ to $0$ as $m$ goes to infinity.

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The result is wrong. You cannot even get pointwise convergence on a sequence $(m_k,n_k)\to (\infty,\infty)$ if, e.g., the $u_n$ are a typical highly oscillatory sequence of functions with a joint compact support. In that case you just have $f_m u_n = u_n$ for $k$ large enough and the $u_n$ do not converge pointwise (on any subsequence).

Comment: hi Julian ,I have an other question if we suppose that   $||f_2(\frac{x}{m})u_{n}||_{L^2(R^n)}$ goes to $0 $ as $m$ goes to $+\infty$ ,is it possible to extruct from $u_n$ a subsequence that converges stongly?